# Как объединить update: и message: в types.ChatMemberUpdated?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать, update: и message: в types.ChatMemberUpdated чтобы, 2 вместе работали, а не только один

```python
@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def chat_member(message: types.ChatMemberUpdated):

@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def chat_member(update: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
```

Если, пишу так:

```python
@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def chat_member(message, update: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
TypeError: chat_member() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'
TypeError: chat_member() отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент: «обновить»
```

Answer (score 0):

`chat_member_handler()` принимает один аргумент, а вы пытаетесь указать ему два, причем абсолютно одинаковых. Разница между `message: types.ChatMemberUpdated` и `update: types.ChatMemberUpdated` заключается лишь в том, что  в дальнейшем вы будете обращаться к объекту `ChatMemberUpdated` либо через `message`, либо через `update`. Можете сами в этом убедиться написав простейший хэндлер:

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('msg'))
async def cmd_msg(message: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
    print(message)

@dp.message_handler(Command('upd'))
async def cmd_upd(update: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
    print(update)
```

и посмотрите что вам выдаст `print` при запуске команды `/msg` и `/upd`

Comment: Мне нужно, в '@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def chat_member(message: types.ChatMemberUpdated):' кто отписался, от канала

и в '@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def chat_member(update: types.ChatMemberUpdated):' кто подписался, но проблема, что '@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def chat_member(message: types.ChatMemberUpdated):' не срабатывает

Comment: update: types.ChatMemberUpdated работает, для снятия ограничения, в группе, но не хочет работать правильно, так как, если через else или if not при подписке к группе, лента в группе, сразу закрывается и это, не правильно, мне нужно, чтобы пользователь, присоединившись к группе, смог отправить 1 сообщение, только, чтобы тогда, установились ограничения и как раз, для этого, мне нужен 2 message: types.ChatMemberUpdated